# Wpf browser inside scrollviewer focus

Tags: wpf, scrollviewer, awesomium

I am using WPF Webbrowser inside a Scrollviewer control and while clicking on the browser control for the first time , its shifting the focus of the control
Example: In my browser i opened an html page and the html page had a button . If i opened the web page in the browser [ But the browser is inside the scrollbar ] and i clicked on the button on browser [ or at any position of the browser for the first time] , it causes the browser setting focus on browser [ i can see a small change in position of browser to top left corner of scrollviewer] then only i can do my actions on browser. I have to click on the button for the second time to do the things

Comment: Try setting the focusable to false or perhaps try setting a different focus scope for the browser by focus manger.

Comment: Setting focusable to false did'nt help. How can i  setting a different focus scope for the browser by focus manger?

Comment: as a try set `FocusManager.IsFocusScope="true"` on browser and see if behavior change and is acceptable. however this may create focus confusion if there are other controls on the window, you may see two input carets.